# get all possible permutations of words in string using perl script

Tags: perl, permutation, cpu-word

I have a string like this , `how are you` , I want to get all possible shuffle of word like

```
how are you
are how you
you how are
you are how
are you how
how you are
```

How can I make it in `perl` script , i've tried the `shuffle` function but it returns only one string of shuffle .
If you are not familiar with `Perl` script, you can tell me the logic only.

**Note:** The words count in string are not constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're talking about are [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). This can be done in Perl with the [`Algorithm::Permute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Permute) module:

If you've installed the module, here's a shell one-liner that will do it for you:

```
perl -e'
 use Algorithm::Permute qw();
 my $str = $ARGV[0]; 
 my @arr = split(/\s+/,$str);
 my $ap = new Algorithm::Permute(\@arr); 
 while (my @res = $ap->next()) { print("@res\n"); }
' 'how are you';
## you are how
## are you how
## are how you
## you how are
## how you are
## how are you
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [List::Permutor](http://search.cpan.org/~phoenix/List-Permutor-0.022/Permutor.pm) CPAN module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Permutor;

my $perm = new List::Permutor qw/ how are you /;
while (my @set = $perm->next)
{
  print "@set\n";
}
```

Output:

```
how are you
how you are
are how you
are you how
you how are
you are how
```

As *bgoldst* suggested [Algorithm::Permute](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Permute/Permute.pm), for faster execution you can write this without using *while loop*:

```
use Algorithm::Permute;
my @array = qw(how are you);
Algorithm::Permute::permute {
    print "@array\n";
}@array;
```